# how to precalcuate the deployed contract address

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, uniswap, addresses, create2

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol";
contract TestERC20 {

    address public _pair = address(0);
    constructor() public {
        
    }

    function getPreAddress() public view returns (
        address, address
    ) {
      address factory = address(this);
      address token0 = 0xCAFE000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
      address token1 = 0xF00D000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!

      address pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        hex'ff',
        factory,
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
        hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
      ))));      
      return (pair, _pair);
  }

  function createPair() public {
      require(_pair == address(0), 'Pair already created');
      address token0 = 0xCAFE000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
      address token1 = 0xF00D000000000000000000000000000000000000; // change me!
      bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
      bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
      address dep;
      assembly {
            dep := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
      _pair = dep;
  }
}
```

I tried to deploy the UniswapV2Pair contract and compare the calculated address and deployed address.

Unfortunately, two addresses are different.

After create pair by `createPair()`, `getPreAddress()` return different two address.

How can I create the Pair and pre-get the pair address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 address pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
        hex'ff',
        factory,
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
        keccak256(type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode)
        // hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
      ))));
```

Please update the code like this.

Comment: doesn't work with solidity 0.8.*

Answer (score 3):

```
function getCreate2Address(
  factoryAddress,
  [tokenA, tokenB],
  bytecode
) {
  const [token0, token1] = tokenA < tokenB ? [tokenA, tokenB] : [tokenB, tokenA]
  const create2Inputs = [
    '0xff',
    factoryAddress,
    keccak256(solidityPack(['address', 'address'], [token0, token1])),
    keccak256(bytecode)
  ]
  const sanitizedInputs = `0x${create2Inputs.map(i => i.slice(2)).join('')}`
  return getAddress(`0x${keccak256(sanitizedInputs).slice(-40)}`)
}
```

The deployed contract address could be calculated.

This is a JavaScript JavaScript function to calculate the contract address deployed by create2 code.

Comment: It's working, but I hope to predict the address in the smart contract.

Comment: Works great! Just a notice for the readers - `keccak256(bytecode)` is the INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH of the factory